# Hide HeaderTemplate of asp Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

i want to hide some row in headerTemplate block in my asp.net page
this is my apsx page code:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
  <table class="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-table-striped">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="uk-width-1-10">numbr 1</th>
            <th class="uk-width-1-10">numbr 2</th>
            <th class="uk-width-2-10">numbr 3</th>                                            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                                                                                       
</HeaderTemplate>                                            
<ItemTemplate>
...
```

and i chenged to this to Hide number 3

```
<HeaderTemplate>
  <table class="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-table-striped">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="uk-width-1-10">numbr 1</th>
            <th class="uk-width-1-10">numbr 2</th>
            <th class="uk-width-2-10"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="tdInfoHeader" Visible="true">numbr 3</asp:Label></th>                                            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                                                                                       
</HeaderTemplate>                                            
<ItemTemplate>
...
```

but in my C# code part, i cant changed `tdInfoHeader.visible =false`, how could i Hide Number 3 in my C# part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Repeater.ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event to achieve this.

First, make sure you set the `OnItemDataBound` property to the name of the event handler method in your aspx code, let's say the name is `rpt1_ItemDataBound`:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt1_ItemDataBound">
```

then hide `tdInfoHeader` in `rpt1_ItemDataBound` method:

```
protected void rpt1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
    {
        Label tdInfoHeader = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("tdInfoHeader");
        tdInfoHeader.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i used myRepeaterID.Controls[0].FindControl("tdInfoHeader").Visible = false insted

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
protected void r1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header) 
        {
            object headeRow = e.Item.FindControl("tdInfoHeader");
            headeRow.Visible = false;
        }       
    }
```

Find your [headerTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.headertemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) row and set `visible=false`